# android : Error converting byte to dex

Tags: android, build.gradle

So, I am getting the following error while running the project after upgrading build.gradle (Project) from

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

to

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

I just changed the gradle from `2.0.0-alpha2` to `2.0.0-alpha3` and then, trying to build the project.

**Error log:**

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:incrementalDebugBuildInfoGenerator
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCustomtabs2311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComDigitsSdkAndroidDigits192Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComTwitterSdkAndroidTweetComposer102Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComTwitterSdkAndroidTweetUi180Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComTwitterSdkAndroidTwitter1110Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComTwitterSdkAndroidTwitterCore162Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareIoFabricSdkAndroidFabric1310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:injectDebugBootstrap
Instrumented app with a fast deploy bootstrapping application
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:fastDeployDebugExtractor
:app:generateDebugInstantRunAppInfo
:app:transformClassesWithExtractJarsForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/R$color
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/R$style
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/R$attr
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/R$dimen
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/R$integer
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/R$anim
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/BuildConfig
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/R$mipmap
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/R$menu
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/R
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/R$drawable
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/R$raw
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/R$layout
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/R$plurals
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/R$styleable
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/R$id
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/R$string
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/R$bool
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/models/WsModelPreference
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/models/WsModelMessage
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/models/ModelPreference$1
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/models/WsModelComment
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/models/ModelGetAnonymousJWT
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/models/ModelInboxFeed
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/models/ModelGetAnonymousJWT$1
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/models/ModelPreference
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/adapters/RecyclerAdapterMessage$1
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/adapters/RecyclerAdapterComment$CommentViewHolder
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/adapters/RecyclerAdapterMessage$MessagesViewHolder$1
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/adapters/AdapterPreference$1
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/adapters/RecyclerAdapterMessage$MessagesViewHolder
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/adapters/RecyclerAdapterComment
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/adapters/RecyclerAdapterMessage
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/adapters/AdapterPreference
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/adapters/RecyclerAdapterMessage$MessagesViewHolder$2
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/fragments/DummyFragment$1
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/fragments/DialogFragmentUserProfile$2
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/fragments/FragmentPlaceholder$2
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/fragments/DialogFragmentUserProfile$4
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/fragments/FragmentPlaceholder
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/fragments/DialogFragmentComment
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/fragments/DialogFragmentUserProfile$5
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/fragments/FragmentPlaceholder$1
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/fragments/DialogFragmentUserProfile$6
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/fragments/DialogFragmentUserProfile$1
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/fragments/DialogFragmentUserProfile
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/fragments/DialogFragmentUserProfile$3
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/fragments/FragmentPlaceholder$VerticalSpaceItemDecoration
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/fragments/DummyFragment
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/fragments/FragmentPlaceholder$3
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/constants/WsConstant
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/constants/ToolBarCustom$1
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/constants/ToolBarCustom
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/app/MainActivity$5
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/app/MainActivity$2
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/app/SplashActivity
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/app/MainActivity
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/app/MainActivity$1
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/app/MainActivity$4
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/app/MainActivity$6
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/app/MainActivity$3
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/app/MainActivity$SectionsPagerAdapter
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/helpers/ServiceConnection
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/helpers/WebviewFallback
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/helpers/KeepAliveService
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/helpers/HelperVolley$1
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/helpers/CustomTabsHelper
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/helpers/HelperVolley
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/helpers/HelperPreferences
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/helpers/CustomTabActivityHelper
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/waysay/helpers/WebviewActivity
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/design/R$color
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/design/R$style
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/design/R$attr
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/design/R$dimen
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/design/R$integer
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/design/R$anim
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/design/R
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/design/R$drawable
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/design/R$layout
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/design/R$styleable
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/design/R$id
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/design/R$string
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/design/R$bool
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/R$color
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/R$style
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/R$attr
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/R$dimen
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/R$integer
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/R$anim
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/R
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/R$drawable
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/R$raw
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/R$layout
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/R$plurals
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/R$styleable
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/R$id
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/R$string
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/R$bool
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/digits/sdk/android/R$color
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/digits/sdk/android/R$style
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/digits/sdk/android/R$attr
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/digits/sdk/android/R$dimen
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/digits/sdk/android/R$integer
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/digits/sdk/android/R$anim
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/digits/sdk/android/R
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/digits/sdk/android/R$drawable
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/digits/sdk/android/R$raw
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/digits/sdk/android/R$layout
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/digits/sdk/android/R$styleable
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/digits/sdk/android/R$id
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/digits/sdk/android/R$string
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/digits/sdk/android/R$bool
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/v7/cardview/R$color
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/v7/cardview/R$style
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/v7/cardview/R$attr
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/v7/cardview/R$dimen
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/v7/cardview/R
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/v7/cardview/R$styleable
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/v7/appcompat/R$color
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/v7/appcompat/R$style
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/v7/appcompat/R$attr
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/v7/appcompat/R$dimen
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/v7/appcompat/R$integer
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/v7/appcompat/R$anim
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/v7/appcompat/R
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/v7/appcompat/R$drawable
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/v7/appcompat/R$layout
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/v7/appcompat/R$id
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/v7/appcompat/R$string
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/v7/appcompat/R$bool
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/v7/recyclerview/R$attr
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/v7/recyclerview/R$dimen
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/v7/recyclerview/R
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/v7/recyclerview/R$styleable
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting android/support/v7/recyclerview/R$id
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/core/R$color
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/core/R$style
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/core/R$attr
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/core/R$dimen
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/core/R
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/core/R$drawable
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/core/R$raw
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/core/R$layout
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/core/R$styleable
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/core/R$id
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/core/R$string
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/tweetcomposer/R$color
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/tweetcomposer/R$style
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/tweetcomposer/R$attr
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/tweetcomposer/R$dimen
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/tweetcomposer/R
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/tweetcomposer/R$drawable
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/tweetcomposer/R$raw
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/tweetcomposer/R$layout
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/tweetcomposer/R$styleable
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/tweetcomposer/R$id
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/tweetcomposer/R$string
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/tweetui/R$color
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/tweetui/R$style
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/tweetui/R$attr
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/tweetui/R$dimen
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/tweetui/R
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/tweetui/R$drawable
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/tweetui/R$raw
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/tweetui/R$layout
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/tweetui/R$plurals
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/tweetui/R$styleable
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/tweetui/R$id
IncrementalSupportVisitor Visiting com/twitter/sdk/android/tweetui/R$string
:app:transformClassesWithInstant+restartDexForDebug
:app:transformClasses_enhancedWithInstant+reloadDexForDebug
:app:incrementalDebugSupportDex
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/design/R$anim;
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 1 mins 22.84 secs
Information:2 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: just go to this path [link](D:\App Development\my project\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug) and delete all files and then remove all files from lib folder which are not referenced in settings.gradle. DONE! just press build apk.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Okay. I don't know how but this worked.

First I cleaned the project and then, running the project made everything go alright.

Inshort, First `Clean` and then `Run`.

**Edit** First `Clean` and then `Make Project` also works.

Comment: This question deserves one million reputations. It worked fo me. Just clean the project then click make the project. Just that.

Comment: If you understand this answer well, then it should work for you more. The issue is known to occur when you changed from one library to another of the same type but which was a fork of the old library. Some residual files made your new build corruptible upon building the apk.

Answer (score 33):

In My case, I First `Clean` the project then i press `Make Project` button as **below image**, then it start working. `Rebuild` doesn't work for me.

[image]

And I also **updating Google Repository** is must.

Comment: You are a champion !

Answer (score 15):

In my case, I put

`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

at the bottom of `build.gradle` file and set `multiDexEnabled true` in **defaultConfig**. Then just run and it works.

Answer (score 14):

If you are applying any plugins. Then, in your module Gradle file (usually the `app/build.gradle`),make sure you add the `apply plugin` line ***at the bottom of the file*** to enable the Gradle plugin.

e.g.

[image: For Example:]

Comment: Google! it's not funny when placing matter.

Answer (score 10):

I met the same problem,and i clean project ,some other problems causeed can not clean,so i manually delete dir 'build' ,so it can can clean Ok,then run it ok for me.

Answer (score 8):

I found in my case, this issue was caused by an improper configuration of build.gradle. I had two different versions of com.google.firebase. Once the versions were the same, the issue was solved

Comment: m also using Firebase and when I am building APK it is throwing this error, can you elaborate how to fix it.
`Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzab;`

Comment: In my case, I noticed two lines in my build.gradle `compile 'com.google.andrdoid.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.0` and `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0` The issue was that two different versions of com.google was being loaded (9.0.0, and 9.2.0) even though one was for firebase, and one was for play services. Once they were both updated to 9.2.0, the issue was resolved.

Comment: @AaronDougherty - You are absolutely correct. I was having the same issue due to difference in firebase-ads and firebase-messaging version. I made it with same version firebase-ads:9.4.0 and firebase-messaging:9.4.0 and it is working fine now

Comment: This can also happen if your Firebase-UI doesn't match your firebase version. Check the table here: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

Answer (score 6):

I met the same problem.

First **delete** `build` folder from project location (You can access it via android studio or using explorer), then `build` the project.

Answer (score 5):

In my case the problem was because of capital letters in some packages.

Answer (score 4):

Just `restart` your AS, then `Rebuild` your app!

Answer (score 3):

After I upgraded to Android Studio 2.1, the next time I rebooted, I was asked to upgrade to JDK 1.8.  After I upgraded to JDK 1.8, that's when my AS project had trouble compiling.  I followed all of the suggestions in this page, but to no avail.  Finally, I decided to check the version of JDK that my project was using, and to my surprise, it somehow was pointing to JDK 1.8!

Moral of the story:  If compileSdkVersion<=23, double check that your project is using JDK1.7 as follows:

- Right Mouse on top level module
- Project STructure => JDK Location

Comment: Android Studio 2.3.3 comes with an embedded JDK 1.8.0
When you try to change it to an older (1.6 or 1.7) JDK, Android Studio refuses this with comment that a JDK version 1.8 or newer must be used.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, this was due to my library not being configured as 'android'.
E.g. `apply plugin:'java'` instead of `apply plugin:'com.android.library'`

Answer (score 2):

Check you build.gradle (Module: *your app*).

All com.google.android.gms libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes).

For example: 
If you have com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:**9.6.1** and com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:**10.0.1**

You have to change the firebase version to: **10.0.1**

Answer (score 2):

Please add this block inside android in build.gradle

`dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}`

Answer (score 2):

Before:

> ```
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
> compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
> compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
> compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
> ```

After:

> ```
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
> compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
> compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
> compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
> ```

Finally got resolved.

Answer (score 2):

My project used an external library with heterogeneous Java compatibility versions in my `build.gradle` files (1.7 and 1.8). 
I fixed it by using the same version for the lib and for the app project. In my case for both :

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

Comment: Very similar in my case. I was using 3rd party JARs, one compiled with 1.4 and the other with 1.5 source and target compatibility. I had to recompile them (luckily both were open source) myself with changed parameters for both to 1.7 because my DEX did not allow 1.8 or newer JARS - but without giving a clear reason, it had issues with the heterogenous java compatibilities of those 3rd party JARs.

Answer (score 2):

If you bring in to the code same library from 2 different sources that will cause the error.

Comment: You are right, but you should give further information instead of a simple statement

Answer (score 2):

This problem is mainly in gradle or in misversioned libraries, including,  from libraries, when both define the same class. Expand and check, imported external libraries...

You cannot have two same classes to be exported to one place, or code, therefore, dexer does not know which one should be used...

Answer (score 1):

For some reasons, @ChintanSoni's answer didn't worked. I tried deleting the `build` folder manually but couldn't delete some files since they were being used by some process. Cleaning and re-building the project didn't help so I opened `task manager`, selected `JAVA(TM) Platform SE binary` and pressed on 'End task`.

Then I tried to run the project once again and it started compiling fine.

Comment: It is Android Studio who locks the files. Just close Android Studio, delete the build directory, Rebuild project

Comment: I tried that but that doesn't close JAVA process. Only closing that process manually worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile fileTree(include: 'Parse-*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-alpha1'
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:9.2.0"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.2.0"
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'
}
```

I add the `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0` line and choose the same version (9.2.0) for all firebase libraries and the issue was solved.

Comment: I also had a Analytics library, and I had to change the version of that library, setting the same version that Firebase libraries.                                      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.2.0'

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple projects, make sure you are not adding a dependency multiple times, I needed to exclude the other project's dependency like this:

```
compile(project(':OtherProject-SDK')) {
    compile.exclude module: 'play-services-gcm'
    compile.exclude module: 'play-services-location'
    compile.exclude module: 'support-v4'
    compile.exclude module: 'okhttp'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just clean and retry solved for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing via `:app:installDebug`. If it works then it is related to Android Studio's caches. I removed `.gradle/` folder inside my project and it works.

Answer (score 1):

For me was very easy. Just add:

//noinspection GradleDependency,GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'

... and the magic happens.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it is caused by not same version of google analytics and firebase. I used `'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'` and then add these dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
```

So change firebase version to 10.2.6 fix this problem.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.6'
```

Answer (score 1):

This question have many answers but, if you not solved your error yet, this could work:

> Sometimes we import different versions from google products/APIs so,
>   try to organize your gradle file to solve the: `Mixing versions`
>   warning

Comment: Kindly add some code snippet, if you got any. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and realised that the two separate jar files I had in my app/libs folder had the same packages as sub dependencies, which caused the conflict.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed this can happen (sometimes) when editing java files while Android Studio is building.

I solved this by manually deleting the `build` folder and running agin.

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps someone, in my case I was using a custom package in release mode instead of in debug mode.

I just changed the package from "release" to "debug" and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Thing that worked for me.

1. Go to android folder of your app.
2. Run ./gradlew clean

Comment: its just download gradle

Answer (score 1):

First, build -> clean project -> rebuild it again.

If its not working, then in your `build.gradle`, set the `multiDexEnabled` as `true`

eg:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using :

[image]

I had the issue during transformClassesWithDexFor when the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon is superior to 4Go.
By changing my ~/gradle.properties with org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m (meaning I reduce the heap size to 2Go instead of 4Go) the dex then runs in a separate process and I no longer have the issue.

> 14:52:26.412 [WARN] [org.gradle.api.Project]
>
> Running dex as a separate process.
>
> To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.
>
> It currently has 2048 MB.
>
> For faster builds, increase the maximum heap
> size for the Gradle daemon to at least 4608 MB (based on the
> dexOptions.javaMaxHeapSize = 4g).
>
> To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608M in the project gradle.properties.