# Push Notification using FCM in android

Tags: android, android-studio, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

And i am new in `Android Studio` so i am not understand.
I am new in `Push Notification` using `FCM` but i not getting solution.
i m getting this type of error during run time.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.6.0.
```

My App/Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "info.androidhive.firebasenotifications"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
//    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) // old default
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-beta1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is my project gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
//  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
//        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
   }
```

i have update android studio `SDK` nothing to left from my side but i don't know where i do mistake.
So please help me on this.

Comment: error is self explanatory you have  gms 7.5.0 in your gradle

Comment: @Selvin so what i do ?

Comment: change it to the same version as firebase ... What did you not understand in: *Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.6.0.*

Answer (score 2):

Your gms version is 7.5.0, change it to same version as firebase version or you can update both to latest version.

Update your firebase and play-services to version 10.2.0 in app module build.gradle file

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
```

Comment: every time first clean & Rebuild Project

Comment: current i m getting this types of error 'Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/zza;'

Comment: now check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352591/android-error-converting-byte-to-dex