# Error converting bytecode to dex: Multiple dex files, Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, dex, android-multidex

I recently upgraded to Android Studio 3.0, and while running the program I get the following error:

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/vuforia/TransformModel;
Error:com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/vuforia/TransformModel;
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/vuforia/TransformModel;
```

Apart from my main `app` module, I have two other modules in my project. I already tried

- [`clean and Make/rebuild`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34353086/4169014),
- [Use the latest build tools and Java versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37294741/4169014),
- [`predex` to false](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24025291/4169014),
- deleting `.gradle` folder, but none of them work.

Can anyone help me ?

**`app` Module:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.shais.gpsdetector"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        resValue "string", "google_maps_key", (project.findProperty("GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY") ?: "")
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.cocoahero.android:geojson:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    implementation project(':vuforia')
    implementation project(':rajawali')
}
```

**`Vuforia` Module:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/Vuforia.jar')
}
```

**`rajawali` Module:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'signing'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled true
            minifyEnabled false
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }   
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {   
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
}
```

Comment: show your `build.gradle`. Same module causing problem!

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949761/unable-to-merge-dex-android-studio-3-0

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Done. Can you please look at that.

Comment: add `multiDexEnabled true` rajawali  section

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya tried that too. From the error log, I guess it's in somewhere vuforia module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I was able to solve the problem. The error arose because of the two paths of `Vuforia` jar in `Vuforia` gradle. The following two lines in `Vuforia` Gradle are actually pointing to the same library jar.

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile files('libs/Vuforia.jar')
```

I simply removed the second compilation of `jar` and it removed my error.

Comment: You saved my life, this is the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

First, try to remove the `.gradle` folder in your project. Then you need to check for the dependencies from the dependency tree with the following command in **Linux**:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

or if you're using **Windows** try this:

```
gradlew.bat app:dependencies
```

If you found duplicated dependencies in the list, you can exclude it with something like this:

```
compile('com.library.name:version') {
  exclude group: 'com.example', module: 'library'
}
```