# converting bytecode to dex: Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define

Tags: java, android, firebase, geofire

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/arch/lifecycle/LiveData$LifecycleBoundObserver;

my gradle file

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.ayoubdesigner101.Sinbad.sealling"
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 27
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
release {
minifyEnabled false
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
// FirebaseUI for Firebase Realtime Database
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.3.0'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
compile 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
compile 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`
```

**this is the error I get it **

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/arch/lifecycle/LiveData$LifecycleBoundObserver;
Error:com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/arch/lifecycle/LiveData$LifecycleBoundObserver;
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/arch/lifecycle/LiveData$LifecycleBoundObserver;
Information:BUILD FAILED in 14s
Information:15 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android : Error converting byte to dex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352591/android-error-converting-byte-to-dex)

Answer (score 1):

You need to [upgrade your Firebase Ui](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/docs/upgrade-to-3.0.md) dependencies as well as [GeoFire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java/blob/master/README.md#upgrading-geofire)

And once you do, [ensure compatibles between it and the other Google and Firebase versions](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/README.md#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries)

And rather than `:play-services:11.0.4`, please [compile the specific dependencies of Google Play you actually are going to use](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project). That dependency  is all of them, and it slows down your build adding libraries you're not using.

This error also typically appears if you've added any JAR files into your libs folder. For the mentioned class, that JAR would have to be a android support library such as [Android Architecture](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components)

Comment: @cricket-007  can you show me who to do this ,place

Comment: Do what? Follow the links and see that your versions are old?